# stored procedure calling from c# and iteration issue in Merge

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have over a million records in the list. I pass all records at once from table to stored procedure .In stored procedure i have to have iteration to go thorugh all the rows in the table and for each row it takes table row modified date based on jobid and checks if it exist in database and based on it either it updates or insert the record. I feel that my procedure is not correct, would be glad if someone help on this.

```cs
foreach (No_kemi no_list in newforSQL)
{    
    DataTable _dt = new DataTable("table");
    _dt.Columns.Add("JobID", typeof(string));
    _dt.Columns.Add("CreatedDate", typeof(datetime));
    _dt.Columns.Add("ModifiedDate", typeof(datetime));
    _dt.Columns.Add("DbDate", typeof(datetime));
    _dt.Columns.Add("SubGUID", typeof(string));
    _dt.Columns.Add("eType", typeof(string));

    // adding over a million records in the table
    _dt.Rows.Add(no_list.ID,no_list.CreatedDate,no_list.ModifiedDate,no_list.DbDate,no_list.SubGUID,no_list.eType);
}

using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "Process_NO_table";
    sqlCommand.Connection = connection;

    SqlParameter typeParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@track", _dt); 
    typeParam .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

my tabletype and procedure:

```sql
CREATE TYPE TrackType AS TABLE
(
    t_Id uniqueidentifier,  t_JobID  nvarchar(50), t_CreatedDate datetime2(7), t_ModifiedDate datetime2(7), t_DbDate    datetime2(7)
t_SubGUID nvarchar(MAX), t_eType nvarchar(MAX)
);
GO

ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Process_NO_table] // i will change to alter after i create it
@track TrackType READONLY
AS
// i need to iterate all the rows of the table(over a million)

Declare @rows INT
Declare @i int = 0
Declare @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @track)
DECLARE @is INT

WHILE (@i < @count)
BEGIN    
   -- first i check modified date from the database table 
   SELECT  @is = COUNT(*) FROM NO_table WHERE [JobID] IN (SELECT [t_JobID] FROM @track)
   MERGE [dbo].[NO_table] AS [Target]
   USING @track AS [Source]    

   -- if the database modifed date is less than the modifeid date from the proceduretable(@track) then it updates the records
   ON [Target].[ModifiedDate] < [Source].[t_ModifiedDate] AND JobID = t_JobID
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET [JobID] = [Source].[t_JobID],
          [CreatedDate] = [Source].[t_CreatedDate]
          [DbDate]= [Source].[t_DbDate]
          [ModifiedDate] = [Source].[t_ModifiedDate]
          [SubGUID] = [Source].[t_SubGUID] 
          [eType] = [Source].[t_eType]

   -- if the database modifed dateis not existing then it insert the record
   MERGE [dbo].[NO_table] AS [Target]
   USING @track AS [Source]
   ON (@is != 0)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT INTO [NO_table] ( [JobID], [CreatedDate], [ModifiedDate], [DbDate], [SubGUID], [eType]  )
       VALUES ( [Source].[t_JobID], [Source].[t_CreatedDate], [Source].[t_ModifiedDate], [Source].[t_DbDate], [Source].[t_SubGUID], [Source].[t_eType] );

   SET @i = @i + 1
   END
 GO
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error or unexpected results?  if you just want someone to review your code, there is a different site on stack exchange for that.

Comment: whats the site? i can try but i feel my procedure is mess...coz when i execute first as create procedure then the query completed with errors 1.Incorrect syntax near keywork where and 2. The table-valued parameter "@track" is READONLY and cannot be modified.

Comment: if you are getting `Incorrect syntax near keyword WHERE` then you have a problem for sure

Comment: Neither your C# nor T-SQL code compile. Why do you post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a large number of syntax errors in your SQL (assuming MS SQL), but your merge condition is probably giving you the invalid syntax near WHERE, because you need to use AND, not WHERE.

```sql
ON [Target].[ModifiedDate] < [Source].[t_ModifiedDate] WHERE JobID = t_JobID
```

should be

```sql
ON [Target].[ModifiedDate] < [Source].[t_ModifiedDate] AND JobID = t_JobID
```

The `Select Top 1` and the `WHEN MATCHED THEN` after the null check for `@dbmoddate` need to go away as well, as those are also causing syntax issues.

The insert after the null check for `@dbmoddate` needs a table specified so it actually knows what to insert into.

You also need to end your merge statement with a semicolon.

**UPDATED ANSWER**:

Now that you have this more cleaned up, I can better see what you're trying to do.  At a high level, you want to simply update existing records where the modified date is less than the modified date of on your custom type.  If there does not exist a record in your table that does exist in your custom type, then insert it.

With that said, you don't actually need to loop because you aren't doing anything with your loop.  What you currently have and what I'm posting below this is all set-based results, not iterative.

You can make this much simpler by getting rid of the merge statements and doing a simple Update and Insert like I have below.  The merge would make more sense if your condition between the two statements was the same (i.e. if you didn't have the check for modified date, then merge would be OK) because then you can use the keywords `WHEN MATCHED` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED` and have it in one single merge statement.  I personally stay away from MERGE statements because they tend to be a little buggy and there are a number of things you have to watch out for.

I think this solution will be better in the long run as it is easier to read and more maintainable...

```sql
CREATE TYPE TrackType AS TABLE
(
t_Id uniqueidentifier,  t_JobID  nvarchar(50), t_CreatedDate datetime2(7), t_ModifiedDate datetime2(7), t_DbDate    datetime2(7)
,t_SubGUID nvarchar(MAX), t_eType nvarchar(MAX)
);
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Process_NO_table] -- i will change to alter after i create it
@track       TrackType READONLY
AS
-- i need to iterate all the rows of the table(over a million)

Update [NO_table]
SET [JobID] = T.[t_JobID],
    [CreatedDate] = T.[t_CreatedDate],
    [DbDate]= T.[t_DbDate],
    [ModifiedDate] = T.[t_ModifiedDate],
    [SubGUID] = T.[t_SubGUID] ,
    [eType] = T.[t_eType]
From @track T
Where   [NO_table].[JobID] = T.[t_JobID]
And     [NO_table].[ModifiedDate] < T.[t_ModifiedDate]

Insert  [NO_Table]
(
     [JobID], 
     [CreatedDate], 
     [ModifiedDate], 
     [DbDate], 
     [SubGUID], 
     [eType]
)
Select  T.[t_JobID], 
        T.[t_CreatedDate], 
        T.[t_ModifiedDate], 
        T.[t_DbDate], 
        T.[t_SubGUID], 
        T.[t_eType]
From @track T
Where Not Exists (Select 1 From [NO_table] where T.[t_JobID] = [NO_table].[JobID])

 GO
```

Comment: Thx and i did some changes in above procedure based on your suggestions .Now i get error Invalid column name 't_JobID' near "SELECT   @dbmoddate = ModifiedDate FROM NO_table WHERE JobID = t_JobID" and  in insert values..

Comment: Just as you needed to specify what table to insert into...you need to specify the table that you are selecting from.  You're giving it a collection of values, but SQL Server has no idea where those values are coming from.

Comment: now i get this error : The multi-part identifier "dbo.TrackType.t_CreatedDate" could not be bound....and same for all values in the insert query

Comment: Does this fully answer or your question or do you still have issues? If it does answer you're question could you please accept the answer?

Comment: You answer solved most of my problem .But i still have problem with Inserting values.This is one pending !! any idea.. I updated the procedure code.

Comment: What is the current problem you are seeing with the insert?

Comment: I can only update the records but cannot insert the records.No error message.